# Need help attaching gdb to my project

Tags: c++, gdb, mpi

I use VS2k8 to write and compile (but not run) a program using the MPICH2 libraries on Vista x64. I then use `mpiexec` from the command line to launch the program (with only 1 process for the purposes of debugging), and I'd like to attach gdb to it. Simply using `attach` or `gdb --pid=###` doesn't work (I get the error `Can't attach to process`), presumably because VS doesn't compile the code with the right debug info. On the other hand, despite several google sessions I have yet to find the actual command line that VS uses to compile, so I can't just go in and edit it.

Note that the only reason I use VS is because I couldn't get g++ to find the MPI libraries when trying to compile from command line, whereas VS only needed a couple clicks to make everything work. (Yes, I tried the `-I` and `-l` switches, but to no avail)

All I need is attaching gdb to the process running my MPI program, I don't really care how it's done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be a goopd idea to ask a second question (don't edit this one) regarding compiling MPI (whatever that is) using g++ on Windows, if that is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary formats of cl.exe (Visual Studio) and gdb are unfortunately incompatible. You won't be able to use gdb for debugging unless you can figure out a way to rebuild the code with gcc. In the meantime, you can debug your program with Visual Studio directly, by going to Tools > Attach to Process (or pressing Ctrl+Alt+P)

Comment: Unfortunately, the program only works when launched through `mpiexec`, so debugging from VS isn't trivial either. I suppose I'll stick to using `cout` to debug my code for now. :)

Comment: Why not attaching VS debugger to your process after your started it via mpiexec?

Answer (score 2):

gdb won't work, but you can use [Gflags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265944.aspx) to make your program run from a debugger (VS, windbg,...) whenever it is launched. There is also a registry option to do that directly: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\ImageFileName\Debugger